# Android: dialogbox according to logcat response for webservices

Tags: android, logcat, dialog

I am accessing `.net` web services through my Android Application.  If the user is successfully registered then log cat will show 1 as the response. If not it will show 0  and If some field  is missing then it will show -1 as response. so is it possible to show a dialog box according to the log cat response?

If response is 1 then `"successfully registered"`

If response is 0 then `"Try Again"`

How can we do this?

`Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));` with this I am getting the response in logcat

Help is always appreciated....Thanks!

In this piece of code,I want to add the required code to show the dialog box.

```
   Button signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regsubmitbtn);

    signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(0);
            t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    register();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        removeDialog(0);
//   I want to show the dialog box like registered successfully after removing this dialog//
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    });
       @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 0: {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Registering...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        return dialog;
    }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Post some code please, it's hard to understand the issue

Comment: @Egor Hi, I added the code and in that I want to add the dialog box accrding to the logcat response. Actually I am posting my data to server and according to the response I want to show the dialog box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a method that will create dialogs according to a parameter. Then you just have to call this method with a right parameter to create a right dialog depending on the server's response.

Comment: Thanks,but how can we show a new dialog box after that 5000 ms for the dialogbox in my code

Comment: Sorry, did not understand the question

Comment: I am showing a dialogbox for 5000ms in my code.  After 5000ms I want to show a new dialog box. Also which functionality should we use to check the server response in logcat? any predefined functionalities aviable?